# HIVE date range selection with DATETIME25.6 format

Tags: date, hadoop, hive, timestamp, hiveql

I have a datatable with this date time stamp `DATETIME25.6` format that looks like this: `04JAN2011:05:00:00:000000`

How do I select a range of records for example, between `January 4, 2011` and `January 20, 2011`?

Answer (score 0):

convert date to comparable format (`'yyyy-MM-dd'`) using `from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(date, from_format), to_format)`:

```
... where from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(your_timestamp_column,'ddMMMyyyy:HH:mm:ss:SSSSSS'),'yyyy-MM-dd') 
      between '2011-01-04' and '2011-01-20'
```

Or

```
... where date(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(your_timestamp_column,'ddMMMyyyy:HH:mm:ss:SSSSSS'))) between '2011-01-04' and '2011-01-20'
```